# Ubuntu 18.10 and Previous Thunderbird Crashes When Closed

Tags: thunderbird, crash

When I close Thunderbird on purpose, I get a message that it has crashed and it asks if I want to close it or wait. How do I stop this odd behavior which has been happening through many versions of Ubuntu and Thunderbird? It is not a random thing but happens every time.

Incidentally, I have keep Thunderbird closed when I don’t need it as it drags my system to a crawl. I already tried uninstalling and reinstalling and even wiped the hard drive and fully reinstalled everything.

Answer (score 0):

If you already tried reinstalling with wiping hard drive so after that a new thunderbird profile has been created but the issue still happens the only and the last thing you can do is to create a bug report. This page will help you to do it: [How to Report a Mozilla Thunderbird Bug](https://www.lifewire.com/report-thunderbird-bug-or-improvement-1173083).

Comment: No clue how to do that.